# match_parent width does not work in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My RecyclerView and item has match_parent width but the result is :
[image]

```
    <view
    class="android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

and items:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/ll_itm"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

full:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/ll_itm"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="100"
android:gravity="right"
>


<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="15"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="ملاحظات"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            fab:fab_plusIconColor="#ff56ff83"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/d_red"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="#ff5c86ff"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_remove_white"
            android:id="@+id/fab_rmv" />
        <esfandune.ir.elmikarbordiardakan.other.CustomTxtView
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="0"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/txt_takhir_itm" />
        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            fab:fab_plusIconColor="@color/colorprimarylight"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorprimarydark"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorprimary"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_add_white"
            android:id="@+id/fab_add" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:id="@+id/sp_nomre_itm"

        android:entries="@array/degrees"/>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
    <!--LinearLayout baraye ine ke nameshod fab ro weight behosh dad-->
    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        fab:fab_plusIconColor="#ff56ff83"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/d_green"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/d_orange"
        fab:fab_size="normal"
        fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_done_white"
        android:id="@+id/fab_hazr" />



</LinearLayout>
<esfandune.ir.elmikarbordiardakan.other.CustomTxtView
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="100"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/txt_ghybtNumber_itm" />

<esfandune.ir.elmikarbordiardakan.other.CustomTxtView
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="عباسعلی ملاحسینی اردکانی"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/txt_title_itm"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />

<view
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    class="de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView"
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:src="@drawable/mmrdf"
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Make sure your recyclerview's android:layout_width property should have match_parent instead of wrap_content

Answer (score 633, accepted):

In your adapter where you are inflating the item in `onCreateViewHolder`, is the second parameter of the `inflate` call `null`?.

If so change it to `parent` which is the first parameter in the `onCreateViewHolder` function signature.

```
View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.itemLayout, parent, false);
```

If you need the second parameter to be `null` then when you get the view reference on inflating, do the following

```
View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.itemLayout, null, false);
RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
rootView.setLayoutParams(lp);
return new RecyclerViewHolder(rootView);
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me: if I set my rootView of the item to width="match_parent" but it "works" if I set it to 500dp for example. Any idea ? OK, it doesn't work with a LinearLayout but works with a relativeLayout on the item... wtf ?

Comment: @Cocorico can you provide more information.. a snippet of the code?

Comment: Sry, As it works with relativeLayout, I just change LinearLayout to RelativeLayout. But RecyclerView was match_parent, and item rootView (so the LinearLayout) was Match_parent too and it didn't work. First time I faced this.

Comment: @Cocorico I am not sure.. I would have to look at the xml of your rootView. It does seem weird that it works with RelativeLayout and not LinearLayout.. My first thoughts is that it might have something to do with the orientation of the LinearLayout.. but I am not sure.. If you paste your rootview xml I might be able to help more

Comment: Yeah as previously mentioned for some reason this didn't work with a LinearLayout and switching it to a RelativeLayout with this fix seemed to do the trick.

Comment: This does not work with Linearlayout or Constrainlayout. I had to switch to Relativelayout and then it worked

Comment: You should put `RecyclerView` into `RelativeLayout` instead of `Linearlayout`. It looks like a bug in Support lib.

Comment: Still not working for me. RecyclerView is in Relative Layout and item is in Relative layout. I have tried both of them. It stopped working.

Comment: And this applies to the usage of Binding  to inflate views into ViewHolder as well. `Binding.inflate(inflater,viewGroup,false)` fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using data binding you can add those parameters when you inflate from the binding in onCreateViewHolder, such as  ``val binding = ItemViewBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)``

Comment: ymerdrengene,  three times haha, also LinearLayoutCompat is here and also didnt get it working, see @scorpiodawg 's answer!

Comment: val binding = bindingobject.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)
in kotlin above is working with my constraintlayout

Comment: This answer saves me everytime

Comment: Although, i made use of databinding and it worked perfectly even with LinearLayout

Answer (score 27):

Inside onCreateViewHolder(...) method of adapter where you are inflating the view.. you have to define the ViewGroup as the parent.This you will get from the 1st parameter of onCreateViewHolder(...) method.

see the below line in the second parameter i'm passing the ViewGroup. This will automatically match the view to its parent:

```
rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_custom_list, parent,false);
```

///the complete code is below

```
public View onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View rowView;
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_custom_list, parent,false);
```

Answer (score 15):

I was using a `FrameLayout` with `MATCH_PARENT` for width and was seeing the same behavior with a `RecyclerView` + `LinearLayoutManager`. None of the above changes worked for me until I did the following in the `onCreateViewHolder` callback:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                           .inflate(R.layout.note_layout, parent, false);
    v.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(
          ((RecyclerView) parent).getLayoutManager().getWidth(),
          context.getResources()
                 .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.note_item_height)));

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}
```

Clearly looks like a bug in (I'm guessing) the RecyclerView implementation.

Comment: Overriding layoutParams was the only solution that helped me. Anyone knows if this is a bug in RecyclerView? Would be grateful for a link to Google bug tracker.

Answer (score 6):

I had done fix like this. In my case problem with activity layout file because i am using ConstraintLayout as root activity layout.Might be case for you too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/accent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolBar" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It's hard to believe, but just replacing my surrounding ConstraintLayout with a LinearLayout solved this for me too...

Comment: match_parent should not be used for direct children of ConstraintLayout. Instead, use 0dp with constraintLeft / Right / Bottom / Top attributes.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me.

replace this

```
   View view = View.inflate(parent.getContext(), R.layout.row_timeline, null);
   return new TimeLineViewHolder(view, viewType);
```

by this

```
 View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_timeline, null, false);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rootView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        return new TimeLineViewHolder(rootView, viewType);
```

Answer (score 5):

try this when you set layout params for your item in adapter.

```
 View viewHolder= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
 viewHolder.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
 ViewOffersHolder viewOffersHolder = new ViewOffersHolder(viewHolder);
 return viewOffersHolder;
```

Comment: what is ViewOffersHolder? :) Your code is incomplete

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the problem was in `RecyclerView` XML declaration, the `layout_width` was 0dp which means match_constraints, when I changed it to `match_parent`, items started to fill all `RecyclerView` width:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"  <-- changed this to "match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_max="360dp"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_min="60dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

### Simply adding a dummy View with 0 height and full width in root worked for me.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".screen.gallery.GalleryFragment">

        <!----DUMMY VIEW----->
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            />

      
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/navigationList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
          />
```

Comment: Check what OP is looknig for then post your answer! The problem is not with the recyclerview. It is with the item of it!

Comment: Thanks! I do hate that this is the only solution that I could get to work. In my case it was a constraint layout I had to put the dummy view in.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem when using Linear layout and constraint layout for my compound view used in recycler view, but it worked when I change to relative layout for those compound views.

Comment: After removing anything non-answering, this seems to not provide any additional insight. If you cannot [edit] towards that and according to [answer] please delete this.

Comment: sorry if it is not clear enough, but let this answer stay, I wasted a lot of time finding a solution for this problem, this might help someone in the future.

Comment: The only solution detail you mention is "relative layout". That has been mentioned in other answers already. Sorry that it took you so long, but mentioning only that does not provide anything new here. It would be fine if you can go into detail about your solution and make sure that it actually is a solution for the problem described in the question at the top of this pave. As is, this post does not add anything. Please [edit] to improve the helpfulness of this.

Comment: This solution works fine in my case

Comment: @PravinDesai just wasted 1 hour looking for this stupid error! Thank you for this handy solution. Don't know why am I still developing for android man!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this with:

```
 myInflatedRowLayout.getLayoutParams().width = vg.getWidth();
```

It is replacing the `MATCH_PARENT` with the actual width of the `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 1):

I've been stuck with this problem for a while, and the solution that worked for me was placing 2 views with match_parent, one inside the other.

If I did this on my list item's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#F00"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</RelativeLayout>
```

although it is a relative layout as others have mentioned, and I am passing the parent view but false in the inflater, it would simply not show up at all (red background to check).

But, when I did this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#0F0"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The green layout showed up and took up the whole space.

So just having a child view inside the main one with match_parent solves the problem, no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see your full code, but can guess, that some of the views inside your LinearLayout are '`wrap_content`'. You need to make one or some of them expand to the full width by using '`android:layout_weight="1"`'

update:
you have a lot of redundant `layout_weight`'s. Make them all  '`wrap_content`' and for only one of them add `layout_weight=1` - for the last CustomTextView. This way, it will occupy all the blank space.

Comment: Weight might not the be the reason. But in fairness its been stated match_parent is being used.