# Setting a recyclerView's imageView cells to a specific width and length

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, layoutparams

I have created a gridView layout with a RecyclerView and have also created the necessary adapter class to populate its cells with imageViews.However, i can't figure out how to make the imageViews larger or set a custom length and width for them.In a previous project, i was using `LayoutParams` directly on the imageViews like this:

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

But that doesn't seem to work here.Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, i solved it by implementing the solution to this question : [match_parent width does not work in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691150/match-parent-width-does-not-work-in-recyclerview?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).