# Android XML "match_parent" RecyclerView width issue

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

I have an xml with elements like below

```
<ConstraintLayout>
    <ImageView
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        />
    <TextView/>
    <TextView/>
    <NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_avatar"
        >
        <LinearLayout orientation="vertical">
            <RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
            <RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
            <RecyclerView 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        <LinearLayout/>

    <NestedScrollView/>
<ConstraintLayout/>
```

the issue is that the children of the first RecyclerView don't take the correct width that they can.  (on the children xml the width is set to `wrap_content`)

if I change the `android:layout_width="match_parent"` of one of the 3 RecyclerViews to `wrap_content` then all the elements get the correct size

example images with `wrap_content` on the 3rd RecyclerView (1st image from designer, 2nd from emulator)

[image: example image with <code>wrap_content</code>]
[image: example image with <code>wrap_content</code> emulator]

example images with `match_parent` on all RecyclerViews (1st image from designer, 2nd from emulator)

[image: example image with <code>match_parent</code>]
[image: example image with <code>match_parent</code> emulator]

gif to see the change I am saying [image: gif]

working has is to add as a child of the `LinearLayout` a `View` like this one

```
<View
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Your issue seems pretty similar to this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691150/match-parent-width-does-not-work-in-recyclerview

Comment: but isn't the same issue, I am passing the `parent` as parameter on the `inflate` call with this ext method

`fun <T : ViewDataBinding> ViewGroup.inflateDataBindingView(layout: Int): T = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), layout, this, false)`