# Android java horizontal recyclerview in vertical match_parent not work

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I followed the following tutorial: [Here](https://android-pratap.blogspot.com/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html)
.

Which allows you to create such a thing:

[image]

I modified the layout a little bit.

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#831067d2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#384148"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconApp"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleApp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Sample title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

list_single_card.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/previewImageWidget"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameWidget"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/previewImageWidget"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Sample title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The problem is the upper part where the "Section" is, does not take all the space it should take, its size is equal to the size of the content of the internal recyclerview the horizontal one.

Here:

[image]

I do not know if the problem is due to this:

MainActivity.java

```
RecyclerView my_recycler_view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
my_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
RecyclerViewDataAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewDataAdapter(this, allSampleData);
my_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
my_recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);
```

or

RecyclerViewDataAdapter.java

```
SectionListDataAdapter itemListDataAdapter = new SectionListDataAdapter(mContext, singleSectionItems);
itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setAdapter(itemListDataAdapter);
```

Comment: This might be the same issue? Try checking your adapter to see if you are inflating your child views correctly. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691150/match-parent-width-does-not-work-in-recyclerview

Comment: I have already taken a look before, but I did not understand.
From what I understand seems to be a bug with LinearLayout changing with RelativeLayout seems to work, but I would like to understand why.

Comment: Maybe post your main adapter class, the one that generates the rows. Seems like there is something else afoot here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove the second linear (in   list_item.xml) layout's paddingLeft="10dp" and paddingTop="10dp" and then make change the layout_height="wrap_content" to layout_height="match_parent" for the first and second linear layout and make sure than #fillViewPort Is enabled for both of them

Comment: The problem is not the height, but the width of the layout where there is iconApp and titleApp.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your file **list_item.xml** to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#831067d2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/horizontalBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#384148"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleApp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Sample title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_weight="9"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconApp"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalBarLayout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It does not solve the problem.
The problem is not that the image (iconApp) must go to the right and the text on the left (titleApp).
The problem is the layout, as you can see from the second image, the color of the background where there are the various "Section", its size is equal to the number of the element.
If there is only one element, it will be long "One element".
If there are two elements it will be long "Two elements".
I do not know if I explained myself well.