# AndroidX Horizontal RecyclerView wrap_content not working?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling, linearlayoutmanager, android-wrap-content

RecyclerView horizontal was worked in support library. after converting to androidx is not working when using the wrap_content.

My layout looks like this

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvPlannedDays"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Java File look like this

```
RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(list);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(viewDietChartDayRecyclerAdapter);
```

EDIT:
Item row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tvDayCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorDanger"
    android:text="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sub_heading" />
```

Adapter's onCreateViewHolder

```
@NonNull
@Override
public DayViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv_item_view_day, parent, false);
    return new DayViewHolder(listItemView);
}
```

This is not working
How to fix this issue?

If anyone tried horizontal recyclerview with AndroidX
Please let me fix this guys.

I found the issue, I'm adding that fragment to view pager
but I want horizontal recycler view inside view pager. this also not working.
I tried setting nestedScrolledEnabled=true to recyclerView. Still its not working

Comment: Make sure your `RecyclerView` item row layout width is `wrap_content`

Comment: Thats wrap content only

Comment: try invalidate cache restart.

Comment: There was some issue in earlier version of `RecyclerView` but that was fixed long ago . Add `RecyclerAdapter's`  `onCreateViewHolder()` code with question .

Comment: @KaranMer I tried invalidate/ restart also, still not working

Comment: @ADM onCreateViewHolder added

Comment: Replace `inflate(R.layout.rv_item_view_day, parent, false);` TO `inflate(R.layout.rv_item_view_day, null, false);`

Comment: @ADM Nope not working

Comment: What's the current output of your `RecyclerView`? Can you add an image to show it . Meanwhile you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30692398/4168607). Use 2nd option.

Comment: What's its current behavior if its not working?

Comment: @ADM its not showing anything inside tab fragment

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones I'm using fragment inside viewpager for tablayout