# Why did ConstraintLayout in RecyclerView change its width setting at runtime?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

The list view item for my `RecyclerView` are in a `ConstraintLayout`. The `ConstraintLayout` width is set to `match_parent`. The list view item has two `TextView`s and two buttons. The buttons have fixed widths but the `TextView`s’ width are defined by `layout_constraintHorizontal_weight`. They display as I intend in the *Layout Editor* but when I run the app the `TextView`s are collapsed down to zero width. The *Layout Inspector* shows the `ConstraintLayout`s’ `layout_width` is set to `wrap_content`, even though it was set to `match_parent` at design time.

*Recyclerview.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/lightestMoneyGreen"
        android:paddingHorizontal="4dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

*Summary_list_item.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:Tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animationCache="true"
    android:background="@drawable/border_outline">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/committee_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:textColor="@color/black_text"
        Tools:text="committee name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/contribution_total"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="3.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contribution_total"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:textColor="@color/black_text"
        Tools:text="total"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/rightArrowButton"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/committee_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rightArrowButton"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Expand_right_arrow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/expansionToggleButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_gold_right_solid_arrow_right_24" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/expansionToggleButton"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Expand_up_down_toggle_arrow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/rightArrowButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rightArrowButton"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_gold_down_solid_arrow_lower_24" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Android Studio display of the issue]

Comment: Please share your code how do you inflate your summary_list_item.xml layout

Comment: The earlier post in [match_parent width does not work in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691150/match-parent-width-does-not-work-in-recyclerview) was the answer to my problem.