# Recycleview not showing match parent

Tags: java, android

XML:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
   android:visibility="visible"
   android:id="@+id/itemshowRecylerview"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:listitem="@layout/singleitemforrecylerview"/>
```

Java Code:

```
itemshowRecylerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
        itemshowRecylerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Viewholder Code:

```
 @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.singleitemforrecylerview, null,false);
        return new ItemDetailsAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Screenshot is not available

Comment: please add your adapter item xml file issue in there not in recycler view.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [match\_parent width does not work in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691150/match-parent-width-does-not-work-in-recyclerview)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your custom adapter class, pass **parent** instead of **null** in your inflate method

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.singleitemforrecylerview, parent,false);
        return new ItemDetailsAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome AbdulKayuem

Answer (score 0):

You have use this type of RecyclerView set orientation and layoutManager in RecyclerView and working code shown in below.

```
  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
           app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                        app:spanCount="1">
                    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

```
       recyclerView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

Comment: I used :
recyclerView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
This line ! And changed also in layout. But, The problem is not changed ! 
Whatever, The probelm is solved by AkterUzzaman...